# Efficiently delete first element of a list

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am writing a program that reads millions of acedemic paper abstracts and collects bits of data from them. I have been having issues with running out of memory and have scaled down almost everything I can.

My next idea was to delete from memory an abstract after my program was finished reading it. Here is my loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(abstracts)):
        abstract = abstracts[i]
        name = abstract.id
        self.Xdict[name] = self.Xdata.getData(abstract)
        self.Ydict[name] = self.Ydata.getData(abstract)
        sys.stdout.write("\rScanned Papers: %d" % count) #A visual counter
        sys.stdout.flush()
        count += 1
    sys.stdout.write("\rScanned Papers: %d" % count)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

This is my code without any sort of methond of removing items from memory. I have currently tried using:

```
del abstracts[0]  # This is too slow
abstracts = abstracts[1:]   # This is way too slow
abstract = abstracts.pop(0)  # Doesn't seem to free up any memory
```

Any help would be fantastic.

Thank you!

Comment: It's `pop(0)` to remove the first element, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You've already found `del abstracts[0]`, and `abstracts.pop(0)` has been mentioned in the comments. But I think you're asking the wrong question! When processing a lot of data, you shouldn't keep it all in memory at once, as you've discovered. In your case, the first thing I would try is iterating over your "abstracts" without keeping them all in a list (or any other in-memory data structure). For example, if each were one line in a text file, you could use `for abstract in open('path/to/file.txt', 'r'): ...` instead of first reading the entire file's contents into memory.

Comment: How about splitting the processing in batches rather than adding them all in one giant list? Additionally, `pop(0)` is `O(N)`, if you're looking for fast deletions at *the beggining and end* of a data structure, look into [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) .

Comment: Also I recommend using the [`tqdm`](https://github.com/noamraph/tqdm) library for showing progress instead of using `sys.stdout.write(); sys.stdout.flush()` everywhere.

Comment: Are you adding the same abstract to 2 different dicts, Xdict and Ydict? Why don't you rethink your flow? Can you process each abstract independently using a method like one suggested by @taleinat?

Or as you read each abstract into the dicts, set abstract[i] = None?

Comment: The first question should be "Can you compute what you need to compute by reading abstracts one by one?" if that is the case, use generators and iterators to only deal with one abstract at a time in memory.

Answer (score 0):

To free the memory associated to each abstract in `O(1)` you can do

```
abstracts[i] = None
```

after processing it; this will keep just a pointer and will be very fast.

Much better would be however not even reading in all abstracts upfront unless you really need that for reasons that are not specified in the question.

Note also that the Python data structure that supports quick appending/deleting elements from both ends of a sequence is [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque), not list.

Answer (score -2):

if possible You can split your abstract like 10 Gb data read first 1 gb process it and next 1 gb like it will process easy and wont take much time and memory